USRP read receive signal
i want to check the rx power in the LaabVIEW. I set the tone frequency is 15kHz and carrier freq 2 GHz. at the Tx, the amplitude is 0.7 dB. But at the Rx, the highest power is at the 0 kHz (around 65dB) and in freq 15kHz the value is only around -80 dB.  how should I calculate the Rx power correctly? *there is not "bandwidth" parameter in labview that I use

